# Set images on a 3D cube object - Android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, 3d, augmented-reality

I'm brand new on android studio and I'm trying to create an AR application that will show content on 3D objects.
So I thought the best approach will be a cube.
I'm using 'sceneform' : https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android

So far I'm able to see the 3D cube object that I already have, but I want to set images on it's surfaces (let's say 'image_a','image_b','image_c','image_d').

Later - all of those images will be taken from firebase to create something smarter, now I'm just trying to see if it's even possible to show images on the cube surfaces.

That's my code so far:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArFragment a = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
        if(a != null){
            a.setOnTapPlaneGlbModel("cube.glb");
        }
    }
```

Thanks